# How to get xpath which contains a variable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to get videos length using xPath but the aria-label changes on every video it looks like this `//*[@aria-label="10 seconds"]`

How can i specify this element path
here's the html source

```
<span id="text" class="style-scope ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer" aria-label="20 seconds">   0:20 </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this id is unique `text`

directly try to extract the `.text` or do a `.get_attribute`

Using `.text` :

```
video_len = driver.find_element_by_id('text').text
print(video_len)
```

Using `.get_attribute()` :

```
video_len = driver.find_element_by_id('text').get_attribute('aria-label')
print(video_len)
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

You can try the same two methods with the below `css`

```
span.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer
```

always check in HTMLDOM, if we have unique entry or not for any locator.